# Redirect Facebook App to Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, redirect, facebook-apps

Since you cannot change the name of a facebook Page after having 200 likes, I thought about creating a Facebook App with the right name (the name most people will search for on Facebook) and make it redirect to the Facebook Page with the wrong name. I've already searched 'stackoverflow'but I couldn't find anything that was exactly what I mean.

I've already set up the app, disabled sandbox mode and added the Facebook PAge link to 'Website Facebook login - Site URL' but it is not working. Am i missing a few steps? I already tried entering an URL that goes to a redirect script as well, but that also did now work.

I hope someone can help me out :) - Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can redirect the App to Facebook page only in application details.

You should create a Facebook Page App. 
And put : http://www.yourdomain.com/redirect/redirect.php as Page Tab URL.

And in redirect.php put PHP code that redirect to your new Facebook page URL.

Do you have any domain name or place your can store files ?

Comment: Yes I have. I have created the app, but somehow I cannot add the app to the Facebook page and it doesn't show in Facebook search. I'm probably to new to this.